# Update date parameter in multiple table using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to update the below dates for multiple records in a table. Each record has a unique Id call object_id. I have used the below SQL to update one record but would like to know if I can bulk update them. I constantly receive these requests to update the date. This time it is only 6 records but usually, I get the request to update even 50 records.

[This is the data that I received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBxj0.jpg)

[This is the data in the database table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxg4E.jpg)

I need to update the CASE_DETAIL table by adding the judgment date into JUDGMENT_DATE COLUMN which is currently null.

```
update case_detail cd set CD.JUDGMENT_DATE = '18/DEC/1998' where CD.OBJECT_ID = 5091449
```

Any advice in the direction of creating a SQL script that would bulk update the date column in multiple records would be of great assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your new values are arriving in a table, you can update the `case_detail` table by doing:

```
update case_detail cd
    set judgment_date = (select r.judgement_date
                         from received r
                         where cd.object_id = r.object_id
                        )
    where exists (select 1
                  from received r
                  where cd.object_id = r.object_id
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
UPDATE case_detail cd SET CD.JUDGMENT_DATE = '18/DEC/1998' WHERE CD.OBJECT_ID IN (SELECT OBJECT_ID FROM @ReceivetableName)  AND CD.JUDGMENT_DATE IS NULL
```